# How can I create a View from multiple rows from multiple tables?

Tags: android, sql, sqlite, view, sql-view

I'm building a database for a chat application and I'm having a spot of trouble building a `View` to combine the Chats table and the Users table.

The `Chats` table has fields `sender_id`, `receiver_id` which map to the `user_id` field in the `Users` table. Now, I want to create a `View` which will combine the `Chats` with the `Users` table, and also provide the sender's and receiver's profile picture(in the fields `sender_pic` and `receiver_pic`). These can be fetched from the `profile_pic` field from the `Users` table.

What's the SQL syntax for doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your syntax will be as follows, because you need both sender and receiver you need to join to users table twice.

```
CREATE VIEW SomeFancyName
AS
    SELECT s.profile_pic AS sender_pic
           ,r.profile_pic AS receiver_pic
        FROM Chats c
        JOIN users s
            ON c.sender_id = s.user_id
        JOIN users r
            ON c.receiver_id = s.user_id
```

now you can add columns that you need from each

Answer (score 0):

You've got to use alias names:

```
SELECT
    s.profile_pic AS sender_pic,
    r.profile_pic AS receiver_pic
FROM
    Chats
INNER JOIN
    Users AS s      -- s will represent the sender
ON
    Chats.sender_id = s.user_id
INNER JOIN
    Users AS r      -- and r the receiver
ON
    Chats.receiver_id = r.user_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to `JOIN` the `Chats` table with the `Users` table.

As you have 2 joins to the same table (one for the receiver, one for the sender), you'll also need to use table alias to differentiate them:

```
SELECT Chats.sender_id, Sender.profile_pic as Sender_profile_pic, 
       Chats.receiver_id, Receiver.profile_pic as Receiver_profile_pic, ...
  FROM Chats
  JOIN Users Receiver ON Users.user_id = Chats.receiver_id
  JOIN Users Sender ON Users.user_id = Chats.sender_id
```